# Tastypie full field without external fields

Tags: django, tastypie

In [tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), I have a class A that has a foreign key to class B. Class B has a foreign key to class C.

```
A --> B --> C
```

When requesting Resource `A` How can I fully load class `B` without recursively loading class `C`? Currently this line loads class `C` as well, which I don't want. Also I'd like this all to happen in a single DB query.

```
B = fields.ForeignKey(B, 'B', full = True)
```

Comment: OFFTOPIC: link to kululu in your profile wont work for me. Could you please check it out?

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own `ApiField`. See https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/fields.py and http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html?highlight=hydrate#Resource.hydrate for how to create yours.

Comment: I don't fully understand. Can I setup through my own api field what type of sql query will be generated? And doesn't Full property have any way to customize it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`use_in`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#use-in) kwarg along with `full=True`.

Link: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#use-in